# Generating Random Numbers in C and writing it to a text file

Tags: c, file, random

I've created a project that reads numbers from a text file and draws an isometric projection of it, but now I'm trying to create a program that generates numbers from 0-9 and writes them in the document. This is what my code looks like, but the document remains empty. I'm under the assumption that the error is either in my rand() function usage, or when I convert the integers to characters.

Thank you in advance for all the input, and I apologize if it's just an operator error. I'm pretty new to this stuff:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     main(void)
{
    char    str[10];
    FILE    *fptr;
    int     i;
    int     num;
    char    num2;
    i = 0;

    fptr = fopen("map.fdf", "w");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR Creating File!");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        num = rand() % 10;
        num2 = num + '0';
        str[i] = num2;
        i += 1;
    }
    puts(str);
    fprintf(fptr,"%s", str);
    fclose(fptr);
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your `while` loop, it seems to wait for some condition that it doesn't contain code to make happen.

Anyway, how about not re-inventing how to convert single-digit integers to characters, and instead using higher-level I/O functions to just print to the file? That's why they're there, after all. :)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
  fprintf(fptr, "%d", rand() % 10);
}
fprintf(fptr, "\n");  /* Probably nice to make it a line. */
```

If you really must make do without `for`, you can of course always manually transform it into a `while` loop:

```
int i = 0;
while(i++ < 10)
{
  fprintf(fptr, "%d", rand() % 10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The while loop is supposed to repeat until it hits the '\0' character which should be the end of the string, but as Hans mentioned, it seems to initialize the /0 at the first character in the string. int i is used as an index for the current character in the string. The reason why I use low level programming is because 90% of the pre made functions are forbidden in our curriculum, including for loops. Once again thanks for the answer, and I'll let you know if I get it working!

Comment: Thanks once again, I managed to get it working while using a while loop!

Answer (score 2):

Your "str" is uninitialized, but apparently has a '\0' character as it's first element, so the while loop does not execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE *fn;
int num, n, range;

printf("Enter number of positive integer:");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("Enter max integer:");
scanf("%d", &range);

fn=fopen("number.txt", "w");
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    num = (rand()%range) + 1;
    fprintf(fn, "%d\n", num);
}
fclose(fn);
```